# Key Permissions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want that in roleinfo it should show key permissions but I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

```
@client.command()
    async def roleinfo(ctx, role: discord.Role):
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:   
            dd = ctx.guild.roles
            if role in dd:

            embed = discord.Embed(title="Role information", colour=discord.Color.gold(), timestamp=datetime.utcnow())



            fields = [("Name", str(role), False),
                   ("ID", role.id, False),
                   ("Color", role.color, False),
                   ("Mentionable", role.mentionable, False),
                   ("Position", role.position, False),
                   ("Created at", role.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), False),
                   ("Key Permissions ", role.permissions, False)]

            for name, value, inline in fields:
                embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not enough permissions")
```

Answer (score 1):

im not sure this is the thing you wanted but give it a try
you can find more [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions)

```
@bot.command()
async def roleinfo(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        dd = ctx.guild.roles
        if role in dd:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Role information", colour=discord.Color.gold(), timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

        perms_string = ""
        for perm, true_false in role.permissions:
            if true_false is True:
                perms_string += f"{perm}, "

        fields = [("Name", str(role), False),
                  ("ID", role.id, False),
                  ("Color", role.color, False),
                  ("Mentionable", role.mentionable, False),
                  ("Position", role.position, False),
                  ("Created at", role.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), False),
                  ("Key Permissions ", perms_string, False)]

        for name, value, inline in fields:
            embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    else:
        await ctx.send("Not enough permissions")
```

[image]

Comment: yes this is what i want but i just want it to show off manager permissions

Comment: i think you can do it by creating a list with permissions to show up you want in embed. and check if permission is in the list that you created and then show it

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly. You can get True or False flags for all role's permissions. A minimal example:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def roleinfo(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Role information",
                          color=discord.Color.gold())

    # dicts for permissions
    true_permissions = dict()
    false_permissions = dict()
    # get flags for all permissions
    for key, value in role.permissions:
        if value:
            true_permissions[key] = value
        else:
            false_permissions[key] = value

    fields = [("True Key Permissions ", true_permissions, False),
              ("False Key Permissions ", false_permissions, False)]

    for name, value, inline in fields:
        embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Result:

[image]

Or if you want to get value for permissions: `role.permissions.value`. Docs:

> **value**
>
> The raw value. This value is a bit array field of a 53-bit integer representing the currently available permissions. You should query permissions via the properties rather than using this raw value.